# getDeclaredMethods getting NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, maven-3

So I am loading the class and that works just fine. Then execute the getDeclaredMethods() and getting a NoClassDefFounfError. I was able to trace it inside the method and here is what is on the line.

```
driver = new FireFoxDriver();
```

When I debug look at the detailed message of NoClassDefFounfError I see the following

```
"org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver"
```

What could be causing this? I am using Maven and during the test phase I am having no issues with WebDriver running and doing the test. All the issues are happening in the site phase when it is parsing the class files for the methods. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly there is a method that takes org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver as a parameter or returns it as a result. You aren't calling it during testing so you don't get an error, but when you introspect all the methods Java has to construct a Class object for that parameter/return value and it can't if it can't find the .class file.

Comment: Well that driver line I posted above is called in my test as it opens the browser and runs the test. Once the browser closes and the test phase is done, The report phase kicks in and looks for that class. So my IDE/command line solves issue during tests but not when the getDeclaredMethods() runs

Comment: @jrock2004 if your tests don't call the methods concerned, they don't need to load that clsss, so they won't get that error.